# Google Drive SDK - image metadata

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm working on creating a client app for Google Drive (PHP). Referring to Files API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files), although I see the main EXIF metadata, I'm missing some of the frequently used other EXIF parms and IPTC metadata.

EXIF Fields missing: focaldistance, meteringmode,sensortype,exposuremode,exposurebias,Lens &MaxApertureValue.

Also, none of the IPTC metadata are parsed: keywords, category, author, copyright, caption, headline, byline,city, state, country, sublocation

Question: Is there are alternate solution to derive above data for the images stored in Google Drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: We have added some EXIF fields:

```
"imageMediaMetadata": {
  "width": 500,
  "height": 375,
  "rotation": 0,
  "location": {
   "latitude": 41.8898575,
   "longitude": 12.486211666666666,
   "altitude": 56.819
  },
  "date": "2011:12:31 17:07:29",
  "cameraMake": "SONY",
  "cameraModel": "DSC-HX9V               ",
  "exposureTime": 0.004,
  "aperture": 5.9,
  "flashUsed": false,
  "focalLength": 68.48,
  "isoSpeed": 100,
  "meteringMode": "Pattern",
  "exposureMode": "Auto",
  "colorSpace": "sRGB",
  "whiteBalance": "Auto",
  "exposureBias": 0.0,
  "maxApertureValue": 3.4375
 }
```

Note: using [this test file](http://www.summitpost.org/test-this-image-contains-exif-data/769474)

Thanks for the feature request, we will look to getting those added.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and for considering as feature request! 
Haven't tested but I'm assuming I'll be able to search data within specific metadata field. e.g IPTC keywords will be used to tag the image and this will enable displaying all tags from the collection (specific folder) and allowing to find images by tag. This could help to build tools that can seriously complete with flickr like or album generating software that comes with advanced metadata parsers.

Comment: @ali-afshar What about parsing EXIF/IPTC full data? Is it in plans?